# Build Failed : En error occurring in 'command prompt' during building ionic2 application

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, sdk, ionic2, command-prompt

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.548 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.  >

You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
[Android SDK Platform 24].

Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

**Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.**

> also updated sdk for the same error , but still facing the same

Comment: Did you install sdk separately? You need to open sdk manager and accept the license..

Comment: yes , Suraj I have accepted the license agreements ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have **Removed android platform ($ ionic platform remove android ) and re-installed it ($ ionic platform add android )** .
after then problem was no more. got my build successfully.

## Thanks for your responses all of you.